# Spring MVC REST with AngularJS: error handling methods

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate

Spring MVC | Angularjs | Hibernate

I have a very simple web app that list all books from database.

Page looks something like this....

[image]

`-------------------------------------------`

**Problem**
1. My update method returns not only book object but also other information such as error message, error code...etc.  This causes a problem in my view when I update.

[image]

`-------------------------------------------`

**Angularjs $resource**

> Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

Now this is actually very convenient as you don't have to re-render new data to the view.  But for my case, I really want to return not only the object its self but also other necessary data if when an error occurs.

This is what my update method looks like in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(path="/booklist/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseBuilder<Book> save(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody @Valid Book book, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        /*...
         * Some error process
         */

        ResponseBuilder<Book> rrBuilder = new ResponseBuilder.Builder<Book>(book)
                .httpStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .map(errorMap)
                .message(result.getAllErrors().toString())
                .build();

        return rrBuilder;

    }else{
        bookDao.saveOrUpdate(book);

        ResponseBuilder<Book> rrBuilder = new ResponseBuilder.Builder<Book>(
                book)
                .httpStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
                .build();

        return rrBuilder;
    }

};
```

**Questions**

1. What is a proper way of doing this?  I could use ResponseEnitity but this doesn't allow me to pass error codes when needed.
2. Should I include Error Object with in my Book class?
3. Or should all Object implements an Error interface?

Look something like this..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
@Component
public class Book implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@NotBlank
private String name;

/**
 * other fields
 */

@Transient
private ErrorHandler errorHandler;
```

3. How do you usually handle errors?

thank you...