# Angularjs $resource control what is being returned to object

Tags: angularjs

Spring MVC | Angularjs | Hibernate

I have a very simple web app that list all books from database.

Page looks something like this....

[image]

`-------------------------------------------`

**Problem**
1. My update method returns not only book object but also other information such as error message, error code...etc.  This causes a problem in my view when I update.

[image]

My angular code looks something like this

**$Resource**

```
app.factory("Book" , function($resource){
return $resource("http://localhost:8080/uni-starter/spa/booklist/:id", {id: "@id"}, {
    update:{
        method:'PUT'
    }
});
});
```

** Loading Data **

```
Book.get(params, function(data){

    angular.forEach(data.results, function(book){
        // wrapping each book object with $Resource
        self.bookData.push(new Book(book));
    });

});
```

** Update code ** looks like this

```
book.$update().then(
    function success(data){

    // UI notification
    toaster.pop('success', 'Some Message');


    }
).catch( // some error
```

**Angularjs $resource**

> once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most cases one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

Is it possible to control what is being returned to my book object?  In other words, the server returns objects { returnObj, httpStatus, errors, message...etc } but I only want returnObj to = to my book obj? is this possible.

This is a extended question from [Spring MVC REST with AngularJS: error handling methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538189/spring-mvc-rest-with-angularjs-error-handling-methods) was just wondering if there is a way to solve this on Angularjs rather than on Java side.

Thank you.

Comment: try this `data.results.returnObj`

Comment: Sorry I think my book.$update()... code was confusing..... i cleaned it up. I don't need to rely on defer()  AngularJS $resource automatically renders the result from the server to my view.  I am wondering if I could explicitly set the return data ... thanks for helping